# How to construct a defaultdict from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have `d=dict(zip(range(1,10),range(50,61)))` how can I build a `collections.defaultdict` out of the `dict`?

The only argument `defaultdict` seems to take is the factory function, will I have to initialize and then go through the original `d` and update the `defaultdict`?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

[Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

> The first argument provides the initial value for the default_factory
>   attribute; it defaults to None. **All remaining arguments are treated
>   the same as if they were passed to the dict constructor**, including
>   keyword arguments.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(int, zip(range(1,10),range(50,61)))
```

Or given a dictionary `d`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=dict(zip(range(1,10),range(50,61)))
my_default_dict = defaultdict(int,d)
```

Comment: Is it possible to extend this approach for nested dicts? The following doesn't work as intended: `default_dict = defaultdict(None,{"a":1,"b":{"c":3}})` for example `default_dict["e"]` raises a KeyError instead returning None

Comment: @alancalvitti that's because passing `None` doesn't mean that it will generate None for unknown keys, it will not use one at all. You need to do `defaultdict(lambda: None, {....})`

Answer (score 17):

You can construct a defaultdict from dict, by passing the dict as the second argument.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = {'foo': 17}
d2 = defaultdict(int, d1)

print(d2['foo'])  ## should print 17
print(d2['bar'])  ## should print 0 (int() returns 0)
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? The default int val for me in Python 3.8.3 is 0, not 1.

Comment: I imagine `d2['bar']` should print `0` instead because no instance of `bar` has been counted yet?

Answer (score -2):

You can create a defaultdict with a dictionary by using a callable.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dict_():
    return {'foo': 1}

defaultdict_with_dict = defaultdict(dict_)
```