# Construct a nested defaultdict from dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to extend the approach discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539115/how-to-construct-a-defaultdict-from-a-dictionary) to nested defaultdict?

**EDIT:**

As per comment, the default is updated from the original `None` to `lambda: None`. However, the following still doesn't work as intended:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(lambda: None, {"a":1,"b":{"c":3}})
```

`dd["b"]["e"]` raises a `KeyError` instead returning None.

How to convert all nested dict's to defaultdict?

Comment: The argument to defaultdict is a *factory*, not a value, and None is a special case. Try `lambda: None`, maybe; it's not clear how you *did* intend this to work.

Comment: I believe this is the answer you are looking for: [Return None if Dictionary key is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130768/return-none-if-dictionary-key-is-not-available)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, please see edits. I expected the key path to return `None`.

Comment: What will be the expected output for dd["a"]["e"]?

Comment: The problem is your key `"b"` has a normal dictionary, not a `defaultdict`.

Comment: How should we know if dd['b'] is supposed to be None or a defaultdict?

Comment: @Idlehands, I see that it's a dict. Should I rephrase my question to how to convert all nested dicts to default dict?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, `dd["a"]` returns an int so `dd["a"]["e"]` should throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, you should know because the key "b" exists in the input dict and its value is a dict.

Comment: Wrong choice of key on my part, what about dd['xxx']? Should it be a defaultdict?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, `dd["xxx"]` should return `None`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def to_none(d, factory):
    result = defaultdict(factory)
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result[key] = to_none(value, factory)
        else:
            result[key] = value
    return result


d = {"a": 1, "b": {"c": 3}}

dd = to_none(d, lambda: None)

print(dd['a'])
print(dd['xxx'])
print(dd['b']['c'])
print(dd['b']['e'])
```

**Output**

```
1
None
3
None
```

Comment: Seems like you're manually flattening the input dict and wrapping defaultdict where there's a dict. In general the input is more complicated with more nesting - manual process doesn't scale.

Comment: @alancalvitti So what you want is a sort of mapping-like data-structure that returns `None` for every (nested) key that is not present?

Comment: @alancalvitti Updated the answer, to include a function for any depth

Comment: @Idlehands can you give me an example? After all dd is a defaultdict

Comment: @DanielMesejo Sorry I was mistaken, honestly don't know what I was thinking.  Guess I was too fixated on `to_none` being a function but wasn't thinking what is being `return`ed.

Answer (score 1):

`collections.defaultdict` isn't the ideal tool for this purpose. To specify `None` as a default value for a nested dictionary, you can just [iterate your dictionary recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52260663/9209546) and use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to return `None` when any key at any level is not found:

```
from functools import reduce

def get_from_dict(dataDict, mapList):
    """Iterate nested dictionary"""
    return reduce(dict.get, mapList, dataDict)

d = {"a": 1, "b": {"c": 3}}

get_from_dict(d, ['b', 'e'])  # None
get_from_dict(d, ['b', 'c'])  # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def _sub_getitem(self, k):
    try:
        # sub.__class__.__bases__[0]
        real_val = self.__class__.mro()[-2].__getitem__(self, k)
        val = '' if real_val is None else real_val
    except Exception:
        val = ''
        real_val = None
    # isinstance(Avoid,dict)也是true，会一直递归死
    if type(val) in (dict, list, str, tuple):
        val = type('Avoid', (type(val),), {'__getitem__': _sub_getitem, 'pop': _sub_pop})(val)
        # 重新赋值当前字典键为返回值，当对其赋值时可回溯
        if all([real_val is not None, isinstance(self, (dict, list)), type(k) is not slice]):
            self[k] = val
    return val


def _sub_pop(self, k=-1):
    try:
        val = self.__class__.mro()[-2].pop(self, k)
        val = '' if val is None else val
    except Exception:
        val = ''
    if type(val) in (dict, list, str, tuple):
        val = type('Avoid', (type(val),), {'__getitem__': _sub_getitem, 'pop': _sub_pop})(val)
    return val


class DefaultDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return _sub_getitem(self, k)

    def pop(self, k):
        return _sub_pop(self, k)

In[8]: d=DefaultDict({'balabala':"dddddd"})
In[9]: d['a']['b']['c']['d']
Out[9]: ''
In[10]: d['a']="ggggggg"
In[11]: d['a']
Out[11]: 'ggggggg'
In[12]: d['a']['pp']
Out[12]: ''
```

No errors again. 
No matter how many levels  nested.
pop  no error also
you can change to any value if you want.